# 2014 American Chesterton Society Conference - and a contest

Tags: discussion

So... my wife has already given me the tentative greenlight to go to the 2014 American Chesterton Society conference in Mundelein.  I remember a few years ago on programmers.SE Anna Lear [got herself sent](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2598/scna-2011-conference-report) to a pretty nice software conference.

I'm not sure if SE inc is [still doing anything like that](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/supporting-community-conferences/), but if there ever was a conference that appealed (or at least should appeal) to a majority of users of this website, its this conference.

I tried in vain to start a Chesterton/Belloc/Distributism themed StackExchange site a few years ago I got quite a few people to sign up by spamming the leaders of local Chesterton conferences, but no traction from within the actual StackExchange land (there was no C.SE at the time).

Chesterton and Belloc always tied the arguments in their writings back to Christianity and I think that most everything they wrote about could be asked about here.

---

A contest to build up the number of [g-k-chesterton](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/g-k-chesterton) questions would be a natural forerunner to sending the right man (or woman?) to the conference next year (the person with the highest score in the tag in the space of the contest would be the winner.  Then, the person who goes to the conference would be expected to schmooze and show everyone the website.

Comment: Please see: [How can I get Stack Exchange to send me to a conference?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132282/how-can-i-get-stack-exchange-to-send-me-to-a-conference)  You are well on your way to finishing Step 1.  Be sure to detail your answers to the five Ws. ;-)

Comment: Can the "who" be "the winner of the contest" or do I have to be so crass as to nominate myself?  (Personally, I'd rather just have some company)

Comment: It might be easier to answer "who" if you start with more specific "when" and "where" (and even "what" ;-).  (A link to the conference website would help.)  I'd rather _not_ structure this as a contest for [extrinsic motivation reasons](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42481/the-problem-with-extrinsic-motivation).  Better is to pick the people who are best willing/able to represent the site.